ggplot annotate with a function-defined curve
I'm trying to use a function to annotate a ggplot graph, as in
ds <- tibble(A=runif(25)*pi,B=runif(25),C=runif(25))
p <- ggplot(ds)+geom_point(aes(x=A,y=B))

p+ggplot2::annotate(geom="function",fun=sin)

The above example does not add the required curve. My understanding is that this is the way annotate() should behave...
Of course I could use directly a geom_ :
p2 <- p+geom_function(fun=sin)

but - quite apart from the frustration at not being able to understand how to use annotate() - this would make my life more difficult, as I'm in fact doing things programmatically and it would help if everything was in annotations (it would avoid the need of a special case in the final code).
Thanks !

The issue is that annotate does not support geom="function". First, you should get a warning Ignoring unknown parameters: 'fun'. Second, from my understanding geom_function already is a special case of an annotating function (similar to geom_hline, geom_vline or geom_abline which are also not supported by annotate and will give you a message about that). Third, even if it does, you have to provide an x=, i.e. while geom_function inherits the x aes, annotate will not, e.g. annotate(geom = "point") will not work either.

I see. Yes I did notice that ablines are not supported by annotate, this is clearly stated in the man page. But there's no mention of functions there. And there is no error message, as I recall (replying from smartphone now, can't check right away). Thanks anyway!

PS https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html : "Due to their special nature, reference line geoms geom_abline(), geom_hline(), and geom_vline() can't be used with annotate(). You can use these geoms directly for annotations". Nothing on function here. Ah, well.

If you must use annotate() you could do something like this:
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
ds <- tibble(A=runif(25)*pi,B=runif(25),C=runif(25))
p <- ggplot(ds)+geom_point(aes(x=A,y=B))
fun <- function(p, f = sin) {
  range <- layer_scales(p)$x$get_limits()
  x = seq(range[1], range[2], .1)
  y = f(x)
  tibble(x, y)
}
p + annotate(geom="line", x = fun(p)$x, y = fun(p, dnorm)$y)

